# Fatal error: Class 'Redis' not found in Windows

Tags: php, redis, igbinary

This is my php.ini:

> extension=php_igbinary.dll
>
> extension=php_redis.dll

This is my phpinfo:

> [igbinary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxUU.png)
>
> [redis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/revFU.png)

Whe I was run the code like this:

> $redis = new \Redis();
>
> echo $redis;exit();

The question is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Redis' not found in D:\www\test.php on line 2
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Redis' not found in D:\www\test.php on line 2
```

**Who can tell me why And what should I do！**